# uTorrent not starting as "minimized" even though settings have been set appropriately

Tags: windows, bittorrent, utorrent

Whenever I run Bittorrent (<kbd>Win</kbd> + Bittorrent + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) it will start minimized to tray.

However my settings in uTorrent have been set, yet it isn't starting as "minimized":

[image]

Does anyone know how do I fix this bug?

==
Windows Vista Home Premium sp2

Comment: Notice how that's a subheading under "Start uTorrent when Windows Starts".  It only applies to that automatic launch.  When you launch the program manually, it assumes you want the interface.  (Note that not every program in the world treats this the same way, which is confusing and unfortunate; I'd expect the behavior you expected in a vacuum as well.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the *Minimize to tray* option in the *UI Settings* section, it has the side-effect of *starting* minimized (to the tray):

[image]

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 3):

Make a shortcut to utorrent, then right click on that shortcut, and click properties.  Click next to "Run:" and set the dropdown to "minimized", then click apply.  When you open that shortcut, it will open minimized.

Comment: I usually run torrent like this: <kbd>Win</kbd> + TORRENT + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Is there anyway to get it to work that way ?

Comment: @Pacerier, rename the `.exe` file to something else (it should already be `utorrent.exe`), then create a shortcut to it called `torrent` or `bittorrent` or whatever and put it somewhere in your path.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your uTorrent shortcut or entry in the Registry that launches uTorrent and you want minimized.

At the end of the path including the uTorrent.exe file, add:

```
 /MINIMIZED
```

That's a space, then   `/MINIMIZED`.

Comment: I checked mine and oddly it already had the ` /MINIMIZED` at the end of the path. For some reason, it's not being respected. Any idea why?

Comment: Btw, for anyone looking for it, the registry location is: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: This works as of Feb. 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for `/MINIMIZED` parameter, it works perfectly (parameters must be separated each other with a space, and also from command with a space).

Also you can run it from command line with `...full_path...\uTorrent.exe /MINIMIZED`  or if you have its path in the `%PATH%` variable with just WIN+R, `uTorrent /MINIMIZED`.

To avoid problems with spaces on paths, on the shortcut add `"` before and after de exe, so it looks like `"..._full_path...\file.exe" /parameter1 /parameter2 ...and_so_on...`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I made it work on Windows 10:

1. Go to "Utorrent"/"Options"/"Preferences"/"General"
   and uncheck "Start uTorrent when Windows starts";
2. Check "Start Minimized";
3. Find `utorrent.exe` (usually in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`) and create a shortcut;
4. Copy that shortcut into your startup folder (usually in `C:\Users\ 
   [username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`);
5. On that shortcut, right click, "Properties",
   and next to "Run", select "Minimized";

Click OK, and restart Windows. 
That's it, that's the only way it worked for me.