# utorrent doesn't close when I close it

Tags: utorrent

If I "close" the utorrent program, why doesn't it stop? I had about 15 torrents active,
many of them nowhere near completion. Late at night, I "closed" the utorrent program 
(using the "X" button) and left the computer running. The next afternoon, I "started"
utorrent again and found all the files had completed. I think there is a trust issue here
if I can't believe that this program will stop when I want it to stop. Is there some
special measure I should take to be sure utorrent doesn't operate in the background
when I don't want it to operate?

Comment: This is by designed and the default configuration of the application

Comment: Well, OK, but I am more than a bit pissed at this because utorrent

Comment: In the settings, there is a setting `Close button closes to tray`. Uncheck that

Comment: A window's `X` button closes that window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @earnie for finding the right setting!

Try using File > Exit. uTorrent doesn't close when you click the X, it just goes into the system tray (becoming a background process, essentially). You can also right-click on the uTorrent icon in the system tray and click Exit.

You may be able to change this behavior by going into uTorrent's settings. I don't have it installed here, but I think there's a checkbox for `Minimize minimized uT to tray`. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/452342/277117) for a screen shot.

Comment: I'm sorry - I misspoke there. I'll clarify - Thank you.

Comment: Screenshot attached to http://superuser.com/a/452342/85121 seems to suggest you have to uncheck the `Close closes uT to tray`.  Edit: [manual confirms](http://www.netcheif.com/Articles/uTorrent/html/AppendixA_02_02.html) that that's the setting

Comment: I guess I'm showing my ignorance here but I always thought close meant close and as far as I know most other programs do actually close. I don't think an ordinary user should have to parse the niceties among "close", "exit" and "minimize". And I'm glad I noticed this so that I can take measures against it. Thanks for the kind answers.

Comment: Thanks for this Mat (and others) I think the message here is that bit-torrent users can't afford to be complacent and I was being complacent.

Comment: Close doesn't exist Outlook either. To be honest not sure what the problem is, you want to download the files, what does it matter if they happened in the background

Comment: Sometimes you need to restart uTorrent because uTorrent fails to work without doing so.